# base64 JSON encoded strings in nodejs

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, base64, buffer

How do I create a base64 JSON encoded strings in nodejs?

I tried this and it didn't work.

```
var buff = new Buffer({"hello":"world"}).toString("base64");
```

Is this it?

```
var buff = new Buffer(JSON.stringify({"hello":"world"})).toString("base64");
```

Comment: Looks like you've asked and answered your own question here...

Comment: `Buffer` accepts either an integer, an array or a string. But not an object. If you want an object to be converted to JSON, you have to do this explicitly, just like you did in your second example. http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
var buff = new Buffer(JSON.stringify({"hello":"world"})).toString("base64");
```

Comment: The constructor has since been deprecated.  Use [Buffer.from()](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_from_string_encoding) in Node v6 and higher.

Comment: This is nice, but why for crying out load the result of btoa({"hello":"world"}) is totally different, i would expect them to be the same

Answer (score 23):

To complete @ladenedge's comment for clarity reasons:

```js
var buff = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify({"hello":"world"})).toString("base64")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always prettify above code by providing some spacing, so that when some one decode it back to JSON String it would look good.

```
var buff = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify({"hello":"world"},undefined,n)).toString("base64")
```

n = 1 to 10 (Spacing)